Is there a way to call the same Power Automate Flow from SharePoint UI inside multiple libraries
We have around 15++ document libraries inside a SharePoint site. We want to build a single flow which is called from SharePoint list views UI inside all the 15 libraries as follow: -

And when the user clicks on the move icon >> the workflow should move the file to OWS using SFTP connector.
Now the issue i am facing is that when i define the flow, to run on selected file: -

I will need to define the library in advance: -

so not sure how i can allow the same flow to run on the 15++ libraries we have? is this possible? If not then is there any workarounds ?
Thanks

The easiest approach would be to have a basic triggering flow per library but then quickly route the trigger body data into a child/another flow that performs all of the more complex logic. Make the triggering flow really light so you don’t have to duplicate the more complex logic in multiple places. I hope that makes sense.

@Skin but we have none-technical people creating libraries, so they do not know how to build even a simple flow.... also i am reading that adding such a Flow (On Selected File) inside the none-default environment will not allow us to call the flow from SharePoint UI... and in our case we have PROD environment where we add all the PROD work, and we do not use the Default environment to store live/prod data.. so i think this appraoch will not work for me.. not sure if there is any workarounds?

That’s interesting. We use the “for a selected item” trigger in multiple environments so I suggest giving it a go.

The only other thing I can think of is using the classic REST API’s to register event handlers for all libraries but you’d need to do that on a scheduled basis or something, that’d be up to you to work through. You could also do the same by generating flows programmatically IF the default environment comment is a dud like I actually think it may be given my experiences. There’s a bit of work to be done though on all of that.

@Skin Thanks for the reply. event handlers for all libraries will no longer be supported in the near future since it use add-ins.. what i am thinking is to add a column of type Yes/No to the site content type named "Copy To OWS" .. and if the user wants to move a file >> the user will set this column to Yes.. then i will run a scheduled workflow which runs let say each 30 minutes, which will retrieve all the libraries under the current site >> and then within each library to get all the fields which have its "Copy To OWS " = Yes..

...then to copy the file/folder and then update the "Copy To OWS" to No or empty..i thought i can make this in a more real-time way but again we have come to a limitation.. so what do you think?

Nah nah, webhooks don’t need to be a part of add-ins, not sure what you’re reading but I’d still go down this path … https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/overview-sharepoint-webhooks … i e done it before using LogicApps/PowerAutomate to register the event receivers, etc.

@Skin I thought you mean to create remote event receivers. but if i want to use webhooks, then what will be the benefits comparing to creating scheduled power automate flow? or automated power automate flow that runs when i set a flag a sharepoint field to  Yes ?

Because you can set them up programmatically, originally you wanted to use an event handler.  Either approach will work.
